# Етишкина жизнь

Tags: фразеология

Попался недавно такой фразеологизм: "Етишкина жизнь" - вроде как, это означает паршивую, несчастную жизнь. А что такое "етишкина" (и какая тут буква в начале: Ё или Е)?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть мнение, что так домового звали, Етишка - уменьшительное от "Тимофей". Но я про домового Етишку ни сказки, ни мультика не знаю, а вот етишкин кот слышала много раз в качестве эвфемизма вместо ругательства. Так что, может, и домовой, может, и просто бедняк бездомный, чья жизнь не стоит и гроша.

Comment: Помнится, эвфемистическое выражение звучит не "етишкин кот" , а "ёшкин кот"

Comment: И это есть, кто как заменяет, иногда бывают самые фантастические соединения, пусть говорят какие угодно бредни,всё лучше, чем мат.